# Dependency injeection at runtime in Java

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I have read through the dependency capabilities through Java CDI but could not figure out so far how to inject a class by runtime. Let me explain the scenario first.

Lets assume I have a JSF web app with a central Email service.

I am defining an interface

```
public interface EmailService {

public String sendEmail(Email email);
}
```

Then next I have a concrete implementation of the EmailService using Smtp:

```
public class SmtpEmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

@Override
    public String sendEmail(Email email) {
    // concrete implementation using Smtp
    }

}
```

Now in my web app I am having a JSF backing bean that should get the EmailService injected in order to sende the e-mail

```
public class JSFBackingBean {
    // This is the EmailService to be injected
    private EmailService emailService;


    public String sendEmail(){
    emailService.sendEmail(new Email());
    }
}
```

Now lets assume the Smtp-Server is down for maintenance. In this scenario I would like to spool all the Emails in a Database and process them later when the Smtp server is up and running. In this case I would like to have a second implementation of the EmailService:

```
public class DatabaseEmailService implements EmailService {

@Override
    public String sendEmail(Email email) {
    // concrete implementation writing the email to a database
    }

}
```

Now I understand from CDI that I can use Annotations to inject the proper service implementation but that would mean that I would have to re-build and deploy my classes in case I would like to change the appropriate service. Is there a better solution where I can use e.g. a configuration file in order to change the injection at runtime of the application?

Thanks for your answers in advance
Pred

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, you could write a custom Producer and Qualifier. Instead of injecting the EmailService, inject for example a "@Failsafe EmailService".

Then write a producer

```
@Produces
@Failsafe
private EmailService failsafeEmailService() {
   // here you can check if the Mail Server is available and then decide 
   // to return the "real" Service or the DB-Queue. 
}
```

Instead of creating/looking up the Services inside the method body, you could also let CDI inject both alternatives (directly or via Instance<>) and then decide which one to  propagate.

```
@Produces
@Failsafe
private EmailService failsafeEmailService(MailServiceBean bean, DBQueue queue) {
   return (check_if_mail_server_is_running) ? bean : queue
}
```

(of course both DBQueue and Bean have to implement EmailService).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I doubt you want to make it so that every client to this email service is aware that the mail service needs to be switched out, even if you used annotations and instance selectors, e.g.:

```
@Inject
private Instance<EmailService> emailServiceInstance;

// few lines down

emailServiceInstance.select(new SmtpLiteral()).get();
```

Which is how you would do it in a CDI fashion.  What I would recommend is that this logic belongs in your `EmailService` and itself injects a reference to some DB class that persist the message to the database until the SMTP server is back online.

Comment: My idea is to hide to the clients whether the mail server is up and running. What I would like to do is to e.g. change a config file to inject the DBEmailService instead of the SmtpEmailService during maintenance and once the Smtp server is up and running change it back to SmtpEmailService. The clients wouldn't be aware of the technical details of the mail service.
Say for instance I have a SAP backend where I place my orders from a web app. If SAP is down for maintenance I would like to switch to another service implementation to cache the incoming orders w/o rebuilding and depl. my webapp

Comment: Well, you're restarting your app then.  I would put the logic of what to do in this EmailService, and only have your clients inject the EmailService.

Comment: Thanks, restart is not necessarily required. If I would use spring this would be a simple change in config xml. Isn't there a more elegant way? Say I am shipping a software that can handle database  or LDAP authentication. I would like my customer to chose during installation what authentication type he would like to use. This needs to happen on the fly via a configuration screen and not via building and deploying classes

Comment: Agreed.  CDI is not Spring.  The closest thing you have in CDI is alternatives, which need to be placed in beans.xml.